# adquery left join alias

Tags: left-join, alias

So i have the following code from [here](http://blog.webactivedirectory.com/2011/06/08/joining-active-directory-data-with-sql-server-data-cannot-fetch-a-row-from-ole-db-provider-yourprovider-for-linked-server-yourlinkedserver/#comment-334):

```
BEGIN
--Create a temp table for the AD results.
DECLARE @ADTest TABLE (Column0 varchar(200), Column1 varchar(200), Column2 varchar(200))
--Get the AD data using the stored procedure.
INSERT INTO @ADTest
EXEC sp_QueryAD 'SELECT adspath, samAccountName, objectGUID FROM ''LDAP://OU=IT,OU=Us,OU=We,OU=Tg,OU=Ts,DC=co,DC=te,DC=com'' WHERE objectclass=''user''', 1
--Join the temp table and production table from SQL Server to join the AD results SQL Data
select alias.* from dbo.ad_users alias LEFT JOIN @ADTest adresult on adresult.Column0 = alias.GUID
END
```

I am getting the results from the exec sp_queryAD but i am getting 0 results when i try to join the two tables. I am pretty new to sql so any help woule be appreciated. I have the table dbo setup as TeamDFW-TEST and the table as ad_users. but I am not sure on how he table should be setup.

any ideas..  thanks....

Comment: I think, you should retag your question so more relevant community members can find it